# SQL Find Tickets Open Between Start Date and End Date

Tags: sql-server, date, count

I currently have the following table:

```
+-----+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| ID  |       StartDate             |      EndDate                 |
+-----+-----------------------------+------------------------------|
|  1  |   2017-07-24 08:00:00.000   |   2017-07-29 08:00:00.000    |
|  2  |   2017-07-25 08:00:00.000   |   2017-07-28 08:00:00.000    |
|  3  |   2017-07-25 08:00:00.000   |   2017-07-26 08:00:00.000    |
+-----+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I would like to know the count of the ID's that were not Closed on each date.
So for example, I wan't to know the count of open ID's on `2017-07-26 00:00:00.000`. This would be all `3` in this case.

Another example: I wan't to know the count of open ID's on `2017-07-29 00:00:00.000`. Which would be result to `1`. Only ID=1 is Not yet closed at that date.

I have tried using another solution here on StackOverflow, but I can't quite figure why it is giving me false results.

```
declare @dt date, @dtEnd date
set @dt = getdate()-7
set @dtEnd = dateadd(day, 100, @dt);

WITH CTEt1 (SupportCallID, StartDate, EndDate, Onhold)
as
(SELECT SupportCallID
    ,OpenDate
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN StatusID IN('19381771-8E81-40C5-8E36-62A7DB0A2A99', '95C7A5FB-2389-4D14-9DAE-A08BFCC3B09A', 'D5429790-3B43-4462-9E1E-2466EA29AC74') then CONVERT(DATE, LastChangeDate) end) EndDate
    ,OnHold
  FROM [ClienteleITSM_Prod_Application].[dbo].[SupportCall]
  group by SupportCallID, OpenDate, OnHold
)



SELECT dates.myDate,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM CTEt1
     WHERE myDate BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate
   )
FROM 
(select  dateadd(day, number, @dt) mydate
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd) dates
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `cte` to create a table of dates that span the range of dates in your source table, you can easily `left join` from that to your source table and `count` up the rows returned:

```
declare @t table(ID int,StartDate datetime,EndDate datetime);
insert into @t values (1,'2017-07-24 08:00:00.000','2017-07-29 08:00:00.000'),(2,'2017-07-25 08:00:00.000','2017-07-28 08:00:00.000'),(3,'2017-07-25 08:00:00.000','2017-07-26 08:00:00.000');

declare @StartDate datetime = (select min(StartDate) from @t);
declare @EndDate datetime = (select max(EndDate) from @t);

     -- Table with 10 rows in to be joined together to create a large tally table (10 * 10 * 10 * etc)
with t(t) as (select t from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(t))
     -- Add the row_number of the tally table to your start date to generate all dates within your data range
    ,d(d) as (select top(datediff(d,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@StartDate) from t t1,t t2,t t3)
select d.d
      ,count(t.ID) as OpenIDs
from d
    left join @t as t
        on(d.d between cast(t.StartDate as date) and t.EndDate)
group by d.d
order by d.d;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+---------+
|            d            | OpenIDs |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 2017-07-24 08:00:00.000 |       1 |
| 2017-07-25 08:00:00.000 |       3 |
| 2017-07-26 08:00:00.000 |       3 |
| 2017-07-27 08:00:00.000 |       2 |
| 2017-07-28 08:00:00.000 |       2 |
| 2017-07-29 08:00:00.000 |       1 |
+-------------------------+---------+
```